# Visual nested tree-like control for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am designing an iPad App that needs a control that allows the user to create a tree-like nested structure visually similar to a class diagram designer or a ERD diagram designer.

Before I re-invent the wheel, has anyone come across any paid or open source controls that enable this type of functionality?

This is the basic use case:  The user taps and creates an entity.  The user taps the entity and selects an entity type and a sub entity is created with a link line between the sub entity and the super entity.

Comment: I think you will be better off using nested `UITableViews`. Create a new UITableView when an entity is tapped & set the title of the table view to the entity name.

Comment: I want it to be very visual like an ERD designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/epreston/PSTreeGraph/

Answer (score 5):

The following is what I found:

https://github.com/LaTtEX/MyTreeViewPrototype

https://github.com/epreston/PSTreeGraph

https://github.com/adamhoracek/KOTree

https://github.com/seletz/CocoaTreeViewExample